# Stratified sampling for semantic segmentation

Tags: statistics, sampling, multilabel-classification, semantic-segmentation, imbalanced-data

I have a set of images and multi-label masks (an image usually has segments of more than one class) and I would like to split it into train and validation sets. The data is imbalanced, where two of the classes appear in about 1% of the images and the other 2 classes have a much higher coverage.How do I go about splitting this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Multilabel stratification is tricky so there are non-default libs that preforms such tasks:

1. http://scikit.ml/stratification.html
2. https://github.com/trent-b/iterative-stratification

Seems this question could be answered faster on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this is still relevant for you, but I came across the same problem and didn't find a solution so far.
Thus, I implemented one based on [Earth Mover Distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html) to find similar distributions on test- and training data.

My situation: I have some hundred label images, i.e. each pixel in each image can have a different label. Overall there are 40 different labels. Not all labels must occur in each image. I would say, a classical data set for [image segmenation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/tasks/semantic_segmentation)

The solution is quite long, but you may only need a part of it. I even do copying the label images to dedicated directories (deactived for security reasons) and do some visualizations, which may not be relevant to you. Therefore, you could get rid of `shutils`, `tqdm` and `matplotlib`.

Most relevant for you, may be the splitting indices `test_idx` and `train_idx`. Using these indices you can split the list with your label images (or their filenames) to a stratified test and training dataset.

```py
    import os
    import shutil
    from glob import glob
    
    import numpy as np
    import skimage
    from tqdm import tqdm
    from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    
    # List of file paths to your images
    file_paths = glob('/path/to/label/images/*.png') 
    # number of unique labels in all images
    num_labels = 40
    # number of trials to find best stratification (the more, the longer it takes)
    num_permutations = 50000
    # percentage of test data
    test_perc = 0.1
    # random seed 
    random_seed = 42
    
    # guarantee that all classes are in training and testing
    min_perc = test_perc/10
    
    # Get labels from label files and create histograms
    label_histograms = []
    for path in tqdm(file_paths, desc="Read label images"):
        labels = np.asarray(skimage.io.imread(path), dtype=np.uint8)
        histogram, _ = np.histogram(labels, bins=np.arange(1, num_labels+2))
        label_histograms.append(histogram)
    # calculate overall histogram and some statistics
    label_histograms = np.array(label_histograms)
    num_per_class = np.sum(label_histograms, axis=0)
    num_per_class_perc = num_per_class / np.sum(num_per_class)
    min_per_class = num_per_class*min_perc
    
    # initialize permutation 
    idx = np.arange(len(file_paths))
    permutations = []
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=random_seed)
    for _ in range(num_permutations):
        permuted_vector = rng.permutation(idx)
        permutations.append(permuted_vector)    
    
    # performs trials and calculate Earth mover distance
    num_test_perc = int(len(file_paths)*test_perc)
    emd_distance = []
    for perm in tqdm(permutations, desc="Calculate diffrent combinations"):
        # test data
        test_idx = perm[:num_test_perc]    
        test_hist = np.sum(label_histograms[test_idx], axis=0)
        if np.any(test_hist < min_per_class):
            emd_distance.append(np.nan)
            continue
        test_hist = test_hist / np.sum(test_hist)
        # train data
        train_idx = perm[num_test_perc:]
        train_hist = np.sum(label_histograms[train_idx], axis=0)
        if np.any(train_hist < min_per_class):
            emd_distance.append(np.nan)
            continue
        train_hist = train_hist / np.sum(train_hist)
        # add Earth Mover Distance
        emd_distance.append(wasserstein_distance(test_hist, train_hist))
    
    # find best split (smallest EMD value)
    emd_distance = np.asarray(emd_distance)
    emd_distance_min_idx = np.nanargmin(emd_distance)
    perm_final = permutations[emd_distance_min_idx]
    # split test data
    test_idx = perm_final[:num_test_perc]
    test_hist = np.sum(label_histograms[test_idx], axis=0)
    test_hist = test_hist / np.sum(test_hist)
    test_files = [file_paths[i] for i in test_idx]
    # split train data
    train_idx = perm_final[num_test_perc:]
    train_hist = np.sum(label_histograms[train_idx], axis=0)
    train_hist = train_hist / np.sum(train_hist)
    train_files = [file_paths[i] for i in train_idx]
    
    # # copy files
    # # Get the directory of the file
    # directory = os.path.dirname(test_files[0])
    # if os.path.exists(directory+'/test'):
    #     # Delete the directory and its contents
    #     shutil.rmtree(directory+'/test')
    # os.makedirs(directory+'/test', exist_ok=True)
    # for file in test_files:
    #     # Get the base name of the source file
    #     file_name = os.path.basename(file)    
    #     # Create the full path for the destination file
    #     destination_file = os.path.join(directory+'/test', file_name)
    #     # Copy the file to the destination folder
    #     shutil.copy(file, destination_file)
    # if os.path.exists(directory+'/train'):
    #     # Delete the directory and its contents
    #     shutil.rmtree(directory+'/train')
    # os.makedirs(directory+'/train', exist_ok=True)
    # for file in train_files:
    #     # Get the base name of the source file
    #     file_name = os.path.basename(file)    
    #     # Create the full path for the destination file
    #     destination_file = os.path.join(directory+'/train', file_name)
    #     # Copy the file to the destination folder
    #     shutil.copy(file, destination_file)
    
    # Some visualizations
    # Bar width
    bar_width = 0.35
    categories = np.arange(1, num_labels+1)
    percentile_values = np.arange(10, 101, 10) #[25, 50, 75, 100]
    percentile = np.percentile(num_per_class_perc, percentile_values)
    for i, p in enumerate(percentile):
        if i==0:
            train_hist_ = train_hist[train_hist<=p]
            test_hist_ = test_hist[train_hist<=p]
            categories_ = categories[train_hist<=p]
        else:
            train_hist_ = train_hist[(train_hist<=p) & (train_hist>percentile[i-1])]
            test_hist_ = test_hist[(train_hist<=p) & (train_hist>percentile[i-1])]
            categories_ = categories[(train_hist<=p) & (train_hist>percentile[i-1])]
        # Set up figure and axis
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        # Bar plot for the first vector
        bar1 = ax.bar(categories_, train_hist_, label='Train')
        # Bar plot for the second vector
        bar2 = ax.bar(categories_+bar_width, test_hist_, label='Test')
        # Add labels, title, and legend
        ax.set_xlabel('Class')
        ax.set_ylabel('Percentage')
        ax.set_title(f'Distribution of Quantil {percentile_values[i]}')
        ax.legend()
        # Show the plot
        plt.show()
```